# What is 1LL or 2LL in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, math, long-integer, cmath

I was looking at some of the solutions in Google Code Jam and some people used this things that I had never seen before. For example,

```
2LL*r+1LL
```

What does 2LL and 1LL mean?

Their includes look like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
```

or

```
#include <cmath>
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The `LL` makes the integer literal of type `long long`.

So `2LL`, is a 2 of type `long long`.

Without the `LL`, the literal would only be of type `int`.

This matters when you're doing stuff like this:

```
1   << 40
1LL << 40
```

With just the literal `1`, (assuming `int` to be 32-bits, you shift beyond the size of the integer type -> undefined behavior).
With `1LL`, you set the type to `long long` before hand and now it will properly return 2^40.

Comment: `long long` was added to the latest C++ standard, I believe. That said, it doesn't matter if you use uppercase `L` or lowercase `l`. Further, there's `u` or `U` for `unsigned` to combine with them.

Comment: @doomster, You are correct. `long long` is an official type in C++11 with at least 64 bits.

Comment: @doomster: Well, it matters for human readability: `11LL` is easier to read than `11ll`.

Comment: how write 0LL in ruby?

Comment: The equivalent in Ruby might be to explicitly create a Bignum, rather than using an integer literal (which will give you a Fixnum if small enough or a Bignum otherwise).

Comment: What is the difference between ((long long)1<<40) and (1LL<<40) ?