# Is this some form of C++ type casting?

Tags: c++, casting

I was reading some C++ code and I came across this rather strange line.

This is the line:

```
if (!k || !n || !m) return min((ll)tot, m*(1LL << n));
```

The  *1LL*  seems to have been answered here: [What is 1LL or 2LL in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248221/what-is-1ll-or-2ll-in-c-and-c)

What i'm wondering is what exactly the `(ll)tot` [2 small L's] could be; Is it some form of type casting? *tot* is a global integer variable.

Could someone please enlighten me, or direct me to some resource where I can read about what exactly this `(ll)variableName` is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's not `11`, it's `ll`.

Comment: You've got `(ll)` in your code (two lowercase Ls), but `(11)` (two digits) in the question text. Which is it?

Comment: I don't believe that's a standard type. They may have a `typedef` line further up which defines `ll` as a `long long` or something. But yes, that syntax is a type conversion.

Comment: Ahaa, yes @Marcin & 'hvd' you're right. It's actually (ll) in the code, two lowercase L's not '(11)' i.e eleven. Ok, so now I should rephrase my question to: "What does (ll) mean [i.e. that's 2 lowercase L's]?"

Comment: Absolutely correct @Dave & 'bartimar' ... there was a `typedef` somewhere at the top. Many thanks!

Comment: And this bit of confusion shows why `ll` might not be a great name to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned before, it's not probably 11 (eleven), but ll (double L). You can try to search for

```
#define ll long long
```

in that code :)

It can be a custom object as well.

```
class ll { ... };
```

Or a simple typedef alias

```
typedef long long ll;
```

(thanks to user  0x499602D2 for mention this solution)

Comment: Or it could be a simple typedef.

Comment: Yes it was a `typedef` actually. Thanks :-) Still familiarizing myselft with C++ so i don't know the difference between `#define` and `typedef`

Comment: #define is only a preprocessor macro... when compiling the code, all ll's are substituted with long long, then the code is compiled. Typedef is a structure very similar to class (only default private/public switched), so I consider "simple typedef" as "custom object" (hm, more like custom class or data type) - I hope this answer is fine for both of you.

Comment: Excuse me, I read something about typedefs, I never used typedef without struct context, I will edit my answer, thx  0x499602D2, vote up :)